# Magnetic analogy to the transistor?

Tags: electromagnetism, semiconductor-physics, electronics, electrical-engineering

Is it physically possible to substantially change a large magnetic field with a smaller one analogous to the electric field at the gate being able to partially or completely block the flow from source to drain in a transistor?
I'm imagining being able to reorient the field from a rare earth magnet using less powerful electromagnets - would this currently be just science fiction?

Comment: Spintronics might be a possibility?

Answer (score 1):

Almost. There is a device called a *magnetic amplifier* in which a small magnetic field is used to control a much larger field by means of a cleverly-designed transformer. At one time it was thought that these could be used in electric power control systems but cheap and reliable transistors took over the market before that happened.

Comment: Yes I stumbled across magnetic amplifiers, while interesting my understanding is that they only amplify electronic signals using control of a magnetic field to vary the gain.

Comment: Hmm, you are right. I do not think that a "magnetic amplifier" as you define it is possible.

Comment: It would be nice if there were a proof though to get it out of my mind -- the original thought behind the question was to be able to switch the magnetic path between a work piece and two opposing poles in order to perform inductive heating (ideally using less energy than required using traditional induction heating)